# java.net.SocketException: Connection reset on requesting http endpoint on Android

Tags: android, http

For learning purposes I need to request http endpoint.

I have setup for allowing http requests, nevertheless I keep getting `java.net.SocketException: Connection reset` exception on the client side and `java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer` on the server side.

When I request same server app with https protocol - all is working. Also http endpoint works fine when requesting using postman

How to make Android allow http requests?

```
<manifest>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

  <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">
    ...
  </application>
</manifest>
```

network_security_config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
  <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">192.168.1.2</domain>
  </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Retrofit setup:

```
fun provideRetrofit(context: Context): MyApi {
  val cache = Cache(context.cacheDir, CACHE_SIZE)
  val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
      .cache(cache)
      .build()
  val retrofit: Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
      .baseUrl(BUSSO_SERVER_BASE_URL)
      .addConverterFactory(
          GsonConverterFactory.create(
              GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ").create()
          )
      )
      .client(okHttpClient)
      .build()
  return retrofit.create(MyApi::class.java)
}
```

Request:

```
@GET("http://192.168.1.2:8080/api/v1/findBusStop/{lat}/{lng}")
  suspend fun findBusStopByLocation(
      @Path("lat") latitude: Double,
      @Path("lng") longitude: Double,
      @Query("radius") radius: Int
  ): List<BusStop>
```

Comment: `192.168.1.2` is not a domain, so I do not think your approach will work. If you cannot test using a server with a real domain name, you may need to enable cleartext traffic for everything.

Answer (score 0):

If it's only for learning you could try calling

[StrictMode.setVmPolicy(StrictMode.VmPolicy.LAX);](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode#setVmPolicy(android.os.StrictMode.VmPolicy))

when your Application / Activity is created. That should make the runtime less of a nuissance when trying to debug HTTP requests.